# Scroll through Kite autocomplete using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, kite

I have been using kite autocomplete in my VS Code as auto-completer. When the auto completer gives me options to choice, I can scroll them through mouse, but to save time I want to know the keyboard shortcut for that. And when I use arrow keys it goes to next line.

[image]

I have searched few things like, but I was unable to find the solution.
I have tried the following key combinations.

- ctrl+shift
- ctrl+n/ctrl+p